# using pointer variables in fortran loops

Tags: loops, fortran, fortran90

I am wondering what is supposed to be the behavior of a fortran program that uses pointer variables as loop counts? For instance using `gfortran`, this program:

```
program foo
  integer, pointer :: x
  integer, target :: y
  x => y
  do x=0,10
    y = 100                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    print*, "hello"
  enddo
end program
```

became an infinite loop when executed. Is that supposed to happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example program is not standard conforming.  You are not permitted to change the do variable in any way (F2008 8.1.6.6.2p3), which includes "behind the scenes" tricks using pointers.

Consequently anything is possible.